# How to override general malloc so I get line number printed in memory leak printout

Tags: c++, debugging, memory-leaks, malloc

I have written some utility code to detect memory leaks when a program closes.  detect_leaks.hpp and cpp contain the function which sets things up and in a program you would just call the start_detecting() function at program start.

Note this code uses the Microsoft debug functions so only applicable to Windows.

My report prints out the line in the file with the leaked allocation for new because I have this:

```
#define new new(_CLIENT_BLOCK,__FILE__, __LINE__)
```

But how would I do the same thing for malloc?  Or I don't mind changing name to eg mmalloc if required.  Yes I know I shouldn't be using malloc, but I have some very old code.

Here is the code so far:

detect_leaks.hpp:

```
#ifndef __DETECT_LEAKS_HPP__
#define __DETECT_LEAKS_HPP__

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

#define new new(_CLIENT_BLOCK,__FILE__, __LINE__)

// The following macros set and clear, respectively, given bits
// of the C runtime library debug flag, as specified by a bitmask.
#ifdef   _DEBUG
#define  SET_CRT_DEBUG_FIELD(a) \
    _CrtSetDbgFlag((a) | _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_REPORT_FLAG))
#define  CLEAR_CRT_DEBUG_FIELD(a) \
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(~(a) & _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_REPORT_FLAG))
#else
#define  SET_CRT_DEBUG_FIELD(a)   ((void) 0)
#define  CLEAR_CRT_DEBUG_FIELD(a) ((void) 0)
#endif

void start_detecting();

#endif // __DETECT_LEAKS_HPP__
```

detect_leaks.cpp:

```
#include "detect_leaks.hpp"

void start_detecting() {
    // Send all reports to STDOUT
    _CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE );
    _CrtSetReportFile( _CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT );
    _CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE );
    _CrtSetReportFile( _CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT );
    _CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE );
    _CrtSetReportFile( _CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT );

    // Set the debug-heap flag so that freed blocks are kept on the
    // linked list, to catch any inadvertent use of freed memory
    SET_CRT_DEBUG_FIELD( _CRTDBG_DELAY_FREE_MEM_DF );

    // Set the debug-heap flag so that memory leaks are reported when the process terminates.
    SET_CRT_DEBUG_FIELD( _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF );
}
```

main.cpp (sample usage):

```
#include "detect_leaks.hpp"

int  main()
{
    start_detecting();

    char* s = (char*)malloc(100);
    strcpy(s, "ABC leak1");

    char* s1 = new char[100]();
    strcpy(s1, "ABC leak2");

    return 0;
}
```

Sample printout:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
\memleak_malloc\main.cpp(10) : {74} client block at 0x00161A90, subtype 0, 100 bytes long.
 Data: <ABC leak2       > 41 42 43 20 6C 65 61 6B 32 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
{73} normal block at 0x00164F50, 100 bytes long.
 Data: <ABC leak1       > 41 42 43 20 6C 65 61 6B 31 00 CD CD CD CD CD CD
Object dump complete.
```

Comment: Why bother? There are dedicated tools for that (like Valgrind) that you can use without having to touch any of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the ask.  I found the answer from another SO question.

It is quite convenient, you just

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
```

Then the report looks like this:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
\memleak_malloc\main.cpp(10) : {74} client block at 0x009C1A90, subtype 0, 100 bytes long.
 Data: <ABC leak2       > 41 42 43 20 6C 65 61 6B 32 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
\memleak_malloc\main.cpp(7) : {73} normal block at 0x009C4F50, 100 bytes long.
 Data: <ABC leak1       > 41 42 43 20 6C 65 61 6B 31 00 CD CD CD CD CD CD
Object dump complete.
```